# zlib compression big buffer vs. many small?

Tags: zlib

I'm compressing a data structure that has many fields. Which is a better approach, to use gzwrite to compress and write to file each of the fields, or write all of the fields to a buffer and compress that?

Comment: Also, I'd like to elaborate that "better" is likely file size for a reasonable time tradeoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate calls of `gzwrite` won't make field compression *separate*: they'll be in a single compressed stream, as if you've written them with one call. If you wanted to `gzclose` and reopen in between, then there would be a difference.

(I think you know the tradeoffs for separate streams vs. single stream: with a single one, compression is better but you are unable to decompress only the fields you need. But again, there is no such tradeoff in your question: call `gzwrite` as it's convenient for you, the result will be the same).